# Search through an HTML Table and find text fields with required classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a validation script for a multi-step form, each group is inside a table and I want to check that the containing table has a required field inside it.

I've tried to implement this as below:

(where a = table id
.required = class, but the classes are like class = "something required")

```
function validForm(a) {
    var myVar = $('a').find('.required').val();
    alert(myVar);
}
```

the problem is that this code returns *undefined*. This is my first time using a `.find` function and I am having a hard time understanding how to use it.

HTML:

```
<table id = "default">
<tr><td>Default</td></tr>
<tr><td>Field name</td><td><input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="35" class="txtfield-cu1 required" title="First Name"></td></tr> <- repeat a couple of times
```

Comment: What does the html look like?

Comment: Just use `$('.required', '#a').val();`

Comment: added the html but it's not that different just a normal table and all

Comment: or if a is a variable `$('.required', a).val();`

Comment: can you explain that line to me?

Comment: It's just a shorter version of find(), it searches for the first element inside the second element. Be aware that if multiple elements exists, you will get them all, and their value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `a` is the table id, you will need to select by `$('#a')` instead of `$('a')`.

In jQuery selection (and CSS) `'#a'` selects the tag with id = `'a'`, whereas `a` selects the `<a>` tag.

Edit: if `a` here stands for a variable that represents the id of the table, then you can use 
`$(a)` to select it.

Edit 2: [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/qVyhx/2/)

Comment: even though a is a variable passed to the function?

Comment: Then you should drop the quotes !

Comment: working great, but it was only able to get the value of the first class it saw. i have like 3 of them with the same clases

Comment: @magicianIam If you want to alert all of the `val()`s of the `.required` class inside `#default`, you can use `$.fn.map()`. Check this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D27eS/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try `$("#a")` to select by ID and not by tag name.